# Need to debug postfix service for slow bootup

Tags: boot, systemd, postfix, debug, strace

I had slow bootup recently and found using `systemd-analyze` that `postfix-service` is taking almost 25 s to start, `critical-chain` told me it was specifically `postfix@-service`.

PS: *I also do not know what is postfix@*

Upon using `journalctrl -u postfix@-.service` it shows the following

```
Jan 28 12:24:10 aaryan-Inspiron-5577 systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)...
Jan 28 12:24:35 aaryan-Inspiron-5577 postfix/postfix-script[1641]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Jan 28 12:24:35 aaryan-Inspiron-5577 postfix/postfix-script[1657]: warning: /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf and /etc/resolv.conf differ
Jan 28 12:24:35 aaryan-Inspiron-5577 postfix/postfix-script[1662]: warning: /var/spool/postfix/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt and /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt differ
```

One can clearly see the 25 sec time delay, however I  am somewhat of  lost here as what how to debug deeper as this log was not much helpful. I have an idea that somehow if I debug the system calls during the start of this service ( during boot ) and see their time lag I will be  able to pin point what is the problem.

I can also just remove this service since it is a private laptop but since this might be a good exercise to learn hence I posted here!

Comment: Why did you install "postfix"?

Comment: @FedKad there  was an open source  mailing software I  was working on sometime before, that  is why it is still there.